# Unable to scan 3.5GB image using C# Twain/WIA

Tags: c#, scanning, epson, wia, twain

I'm trying to scan a 2400DPI A3-size image to TIFF with an Epson scanner using C# (which will result in a 3.5GB uncompressed TIFF). I've tried twain-cs, twaindotnet and ntwain as wrappers (which should use the 64-bit capable twaindsm.dll) as well as WIA.

In all cases when telling Twain to scan to file - just over halfway (the expected 2GB mark) it gives an error that the driver doesn't have enough memory to do that. Unless I set it to save using jpeg compression (as the Epson driver doesn't seem to have lossless compression for photo formats).

When telling Twain to do a memory transfer, it does the full scan, but when I tranfer the memory and write it to a TIFF (using libTiff), the first half is okay (which I guess is around 2GB), the last half is just a single line repeated (still not sure which line, as it doesn't seem to be the last line it has scanned). So even though it doesn't generate an error, it has a problem after the 2GB mark.

WIA gives me a hard limit of 1200DPI, which I think is a limit set in the Epson driver. Next to that, I haven't been able to get WIA to tranfer directly to file As I can't find a way to set TYMED_FILE (and all C++ code I find uses low-level minidriver calls). Also haven't found a way to get the stream so I can write it to a file myself. Creating a minidriver then gives me a problem with an unsigned (and certainly not MS certified) driver.

Any help or links that will point me in the right direction will be welcome!

Comment: 2GB sounds like a typical 32bit issue. Start by ensuring that your process is running in 64-bit.

Comment: It's an extra work, but may be possible scan the document in 2 (or 4...) parts and join the resulting images outside of scaning process?

Comment: @JonasH The application is running in 64-bit, but Twain drivers seem to be 32-bit. I'm not exactly sure how and what TwainDSM (64-bit) does, if it's just the ability to interface or more.

Comment: @Victor It's one of the "if nothing else works" options that I had in mind... I should be able to scan half the lines and write them to a TIFF, then scan the remaining lines and add them to the same TIFF. I'm just hoping in the 64-bit era that I can just scan a big image in one go.

Comment: A 32-bit twain driver sounds like a likely problem. But I have no advice on how to fix it. You may also need to be careful on how to deal with very large data-chunks. Note that arrays are limited to UInt32.MaxValue items, and objects has a 2GB size limit unless [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) is used.

Comment: @JonasH The idea there is to use tiling and multi-resolution. It should be possible to create a MemoryMappedFile of 3.5GB to speed things up.

Comment: Common TIFF files can be up to 4GB only. Files larger than 4GB can be saved in the newer [BigTIFF format](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/to/file-formats-tiff-and-bigtiff-tagged-image-file-format.html) but not all applications support this format. If your 64-bit Twain driver supports delivering the image in one big transfer operation, the LEADTOOLS SDK has the ability to scan it and save it as TIFF, BigTIFF, compressed JPEG or any other format that supports the 3.5GB size (I tested this myself). Disclosure: I work for the vendor. Free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).